# Git Bash does not recognize same command as windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

I am reproducing an NLP paper and I need to get evennia working on Windows 10, with Python 2.7. I cloned this [repo](https://github.com/mrkulk/text-world) and followed the instructions but cant start servers with `start.sh 1`, as it runs a shell script and Git Bash does recognize the evennia command, which is needed for the script, for some reason. In other words:

- The windows command prompt recognizes the evennia command just fine
- However Git Bash does not: I get this error: `bash: evennia: command not found`

In conclusion, how can I get bash to recognize the 'evennia' command, like the windows command prompt does?

Comment: Could it be because evennia is a .bat file or can bash still run those? Or is it something wrong with the bash's path?

Comment: Did you do `pip install -e .` and got no errors? Because looking at [the start.sh script](https://github.com/mrkulk/text-world/blob/master/evennia/start.sh), you'll get that error on Linux as well if the install wasn't done

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Git Bash to use the commands.

On Git Bash type :`git checkout master`. This will switch you to the master branch. Type the home world in Command Prompt then.

Similarly, use `git checkout fantasy`, and then type the `tutorial_world.build` command on your Command Prompt.